# Infinite set of scalar fields in extended SUSY theories

Tags: supersymmetry

When dealing with extended SUSY theories (i.e. $\mathcal{N}>1$) it is generally affirmed that to build a correct off-shell Lagrangian one needs to introduce an infinite set of auxiliary fields to close the fields algebra. I suppose that this is deeply related to the presence of central charges (which is the substantial difference between the $\mathcal{N}=1$ and $\mathcal{N}>1$ models) but I cannot understand how to obtain this.

Following the reasoning used for $\mathcal{N}=1$ I would start with a scalar field $\phi (x)$ satisfying

$$[\bar{Q}^I_{\dot{\alpha}},\phi (x)] = 0$$

(with $I=1,\dots,\mathcal{N}$) and then define

$$[Q^I_\alpha,\phi (x)] \equiv \psi^I_\alpha (x)$$

which correspond to $\mathcal{N}$ fermionic fields. Now one defines

$$F_{\alpha,\beta}^{IJ} \equiv \{Q^I_\alpha,\psi^J_\beta\}$$
$$X_{\dot{\alpha},\beta}^{IJ} \equiv \{\bar{Q}^I_{\dot{\alpha}},\psi^J_\alpha\}$$

and using generalized Jacobi identities obtains

$$\varepsilon_{\alpha\beta}[\phi (x),Z^{IJ}] + F_{\alpha\beta}^{IJ} + F_{\beta\alpha}^{JI} = 0 $$

$$ 2\sigma^{\mu}_{\alpha\dot{\beta}}\delta^{IJ} \ [\phi(x),P_\mu] + X^{JI}_{\dot{\beta},\alpha} = 0$$

how this implies an infinite set of fields?

Comment: *When dealing with extended SUSY theories (i.e. N>1) it is generally affirmed that to build a correct off-shell Lagrangian one needs to introduce an infinite set of auxiliary fields to close the fields algebra.* - source?

Comment: [link] (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9908171) _N=4 supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory and the AdS/SCFT correspondence_ page 25. Here the $\mathcal{N}>1$ superspace formalism is used, but the conclusions should be the same